# SKAction continue working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm using the following to pause my game

```
self.scene?.paused = true
```

When the scene is paused, however, all `SKAction`s stop. What can I do to allow some of the actions to continue to work?

Comment: pause is  bugged,  when you set a node,  all of the children pause state also changes,  keep this in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add certain nodes to different `SKNode` so instead you can only pause the the layer (SKNode) that you wish to pause. It would look something like this:

```
let gameLayer = SKNode() 
let pauseLayer = SKNode()
```

Now when you want to add a child to the scene, instead add it to a layer:

```
gameLayer.addChild(gameSceneNode)
pauseLayer.addChild(pauseSceneNode)
```

Don't forget to add the layers to the scene too

```
addChild(gameLayer)
addChild(pauseLayer)
```

To pause a layer write this:

**Swift 3**

```
gameLayer.isPaused = true
```

**Swift 2**

```
gameLayer.paused = true
```

Note that in this example, all the nodes on the `gameLayer` will be paused, however everything on the `pauseLayer` will not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to design your node tree in a way where you can pause certain nodes (the gameplay nodes, for example), and not pause others (the pause menu nodes, for example). When you set the `paused` property on a node, it applies to all of its children as well.

An example node hierarchy:

```
GameScene
    GameplayNode
        Character
        Enemy
        Enemy
    PauseMenu
        PlayButton
        VolumeButton
```

If you want to animate your `PlayButton` while the game is paused, you can set the `GameplayNode.paused` to `true`, and still have working `SKAction`'s for your pause menu.

Comment: For how to implement this type of node hierarchy, see my answer